# Union different select statement

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

I want to union 3 different statements, the problem is that I am using a loop and if in my query:

```
WHILE some condition

BEGIN
 if(condition 1)
  begin
     select something
  end

 else if(condition 2)
  begin
     select something
  end


 else if(condition 3)
  begin
     select something
  end

END
```

The query is working fine but it returns more than 100 different select results (distinct tables). How can I union these select results into one table?

Comment: Use a table variable select each of these results into that, then select everything in one shot at the end.

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean in TSQL, then you need a temporary table (`#foo`) or table variable (`@bar`). Then at each step:

```
INSERT {name} ({cols})
SELECT {cols}
{etc}
```

Then do a final

```
SELECT {cols}
FROM {name}
```

The choice between table-variable and temporary-table is subtle. I prefer table-variables; but for large data, or if you need an identity/index, a temporary-table may be more versatile. But if you aren't inside a SPROC you must ensure you clean up your temp table.